# How to check MySQL running queries when there are too many connections?

Tags: mysql

Situation:

Something goes wrong, and too many queries accumulate until the limit is reached and new connections get an error:

```
ERROR 1040 (HY000): Too many connections
```

To list processlist, I need to connect too, and this is not possible, because I get the same connection error trying to connect from the console with the root user.

So is there a way to check what connections (queries) are active in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

In the short term, all you can really do is keep trying and hope that you get in there after a connection ends and before something else grabs it.

The max number of connections is controlled by the max_connections variable (`select @@global.max_connections`). The actual number should be max_connections + 1, whereby the +1 is reserved for admin connections (e.g. a user with the `super` privilege or equivalent). However, if you have a regular user with the `super` privilege, that will grab the +1 connection, effectively locking you out.

If you are using MySQL 8 you can add an "admin" login interface that allows you to sidestep this problem. https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/support-for-admin-interface-in-mysql-server/

It will require a server restart though.